# Send data form using <a> as button

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

I want to send data from a form to other php page. Instead of a button in the form I have a  button outside to submit. How can I send the data from the form to the other page? Here is the code:

```
<div class="body">
                <form id="productform" class="form-style-12" action="" method="post">
                <ul name="products">
                    <!-- products added to the cart will be inserted here using JavaScript -->
                </ul>
                </form>
            </div>

            <footer>
                <a href="checkout.php" id="checkoutbtn" class="checkout btn"><em>Ga verder: €<span>0</span></em></a>
            </footer>
```

The < ul > get filled by products using javascript.

Comment: Basically, what you have is a total disregard for how HTML works, and how javascript should be used. As for the problem you're having, make sure you actually have proper elements in there that has been added by javascript (named inputs, for one), attach an event to the `<a>` when clicked, and serialize the form and use AJAX to push it whereever you need it to go. But seriously, that should be redesigned. First - make the site work without javascript, then add javascript to enhance UX. That there is just a fail before it even began.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sending multipart/formdata with jQuery.ajax](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5392344/sending-multipart-formdata-with-jquery-ajax)

Comment: set the action attribute of your form to checkout.php and customize the ul to some kind of inputs or get them with js. then submit the form with the outter button with type="submit" as a button attribute.

Answer (score 0):

A neat solution is to create a  inside the form and style that one.

But you could solve it as you ask:

```
<a href="" onclick="document.getElementById('productForm').submit()">Submit!</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```js
function submitFormData() {
  document.getElementById("yourformid").submit();
}
```

```html
<button onclick="submitFormdata();">Submit</button>
```